# Class not having copy constructor issue?

Tags: c++

I have a class which does not have copy constructor or `operator=` overloaded.
The code is pretty big but the issue is around this pseudo-code:

```
ClassA object1(x,y);
object1.add(z)
myVector.push_back(object1);

//Now when I retrieve from myVector and do add it
// apparently creates another object
myVector.at(index).add(z1);
```

Like I said it is pseudo-code. I hope it make sense to experts out there!

So, ClassA looks like this (of course not all data members included)

```
Class ClassA {

private:
    int x;
    string y;
    ClassB b;
    vector<int> i;
public:
    int z;

}
```

Since ClassB b is a new data member for this release, is the need of copy constructor now become a must?
Thanks again all of you for responding.

```
Class ClassB {
private:
vector<ClassC*> c;
Class D
}
Class ClassC {
private:
vector<ClassE*> e;
}
Class ClassD{
private:
vector<ClassF*> f;
}
```

Then ClassE and ClassF have basic types like int and string.

Comment: (If you want a username to appear in your posts, fill in your profile with the name you want instead of the autogenerated userXYZ name. Don't sign your posts.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is a question-and-answer site. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new object isn't being created when you retrieve the object using
`at()`; `at()` returns a reference to it.  The new object is being
created when you do the `push_back()`.  And if you don't have an
accessible copy constructor or assignment operator, you can't put the
object into a vector; officially, it's undefined behavior, but at least
if you use the vector (as you've done here), it will in fact not
compile.  Most likely you're getting the compiler generated defaults.
Without seeing the actual object type, it's impossible for us to say
whether they're appropriate; if the object type only contains basic
types and types from the standard library (other than the iostream stuff
and `auto_ptr`—and the threading stuff if you're using C++11),
then the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment should be
OK.  If the class contains pointers to memory you allocate in the
constructor, it almost certainly isn't.

Comment: The ClassA does have user-defined classes. So, are you suggesting that i do create my copy constructor for ClassA and other user-defined classes that are part of ClassA? ..thanks all for your help.

Comment: Another thing to note. So far, the ClassA only had basic types and vector<int> as data type. Therefore, i was not facing the issue all this while without me having copy constructor or = defined. In this release we now included a new user-defined ClassB as data member.

Comment: So, ClassA looks like this (of course not all data members included)

Comment: @Jay So what does `ClassB` look like?  If `ClassB` copies correctly, the compiler generated copy constructor should be sufficient.

Comment: For the classes with vectors of pointers: what does the destructor do?  What are the pointers used for?  What is their logical role?  If they're just for navigation, then the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment is fine.  If they're an extension of the value of the containing object (although in this case, why pointers?), then you'll need to do something---either a deep copy (the compiler generated copy is shallow), or some sort of reference sharing (`boost::shared_ptr`?).

Answer (score 0):

The `push_back` creates a copy as it receives the parameter by value. If you dont want to use a copy constructor define the vector as a vector of pointers to your object, and push a pointer instead.

Comment: Just a nit, but `push_back` receives the parameter by reference.  (It still creates a copy, just later, when it actually inserts the object in the vector.)

Comment: also, you can't have containers of references.

Answer (score 0):

It must create a temporary when retrieving because the value stored is a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is using a copy constructor, but just plain old struct copy.

```
myVector.at(index)
```

returns `ClassA` in this case, not `ClassA &`

You should be able to solve this by:

```
ClassA & refObj = myVector.at(index);
refObj.add(z1);
```

---

I put together a little test which had surprising results on Visual Studio.

```
class Boo {
public:
    void add() { a++; }
    int a;
};


vector<Boo> v;
Boo b;
b.a = 1;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    v.push_back(b);
}
v[0].add();
v.at(1).add();
Boo & refB = v[2]; refB.add();
refB = v.at(3); refB.add();
Boo & refB2 = v.at(4); refB2.add();
printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", v[0].a, v[1].a, v[2].a, v[3].a, v[4].a);
```

Results:

```
2 2 2 1 2
```

So the compiler treats:

```
Boo & refB = v[2]; refB.add();
refB = v.at(3); refB.add();
```

Differently than:

```
Boo & refB2 = v.at(4); refB2.add();
```

But I don't get the original problem (that is, `v.at(n).add()` is not copying, but passing by reference).  Are you sure the following line is copying?

```
myVector.at(index).add(z1)
```

Could this be compiler specific?  What compiler / OS are you using?

Comment: `std::vector<>.at()` returns a reference.  And `Boo& ref = v.at(2);` initializes `ref` to refer to `v[2]`.  Forever, references can't be reseated.  So `ref = v.at(3);` assigns `v[3]` to `v[2]`.  (In general, it's very, very rare for a symbol with local scope to be defined as a reference.)

Comment: aha!  That explains why v[3] is still 1.  And it makes sense because if reseating a reference was allowed it would lead to ambiguous semantics.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class which does not have copy constructor or operator= overloaded.

This does not really matter. Unless you explicitly disable them (declare as private and don't implement in C++03, define as `delete` in C++11) the compiler will generate one for you.

Now, if you do disable copying of your objects you will realize that you can no longer store them directly in a vector, as the vector will *copy* the argument internally. You could on the other hand store a (smart) pointer in the container, but this might actually complicate the problem you want solved.

Comment: Note: if he writes just one of the five or so "special" methods (default constructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment) the compiler will NOT define the others automatically.

Comment: @bstamour: Where did you get that from? I am quite sure that is not right: `struct test { test(){} test( test const & ) {} }; int main() { test a; test b(a); b = a; }` compiles just fine, and it uses the *implicitly-defined* assignment operator.

Comment: I could have sworn that I read it somewhere in the standard. I can't find it right now though, so I'm assuming I made a blunder until I can find where I saw it :-)

Comment: @bstamour: I think you are referring about the *move* copy construction and assignment. *Move* construction (conversely assignment) will not be generated if you have manually provided one of the other constructors/assignment on the premise that if you need special semantics for one of them, then the semantics of the implicitly defined move may not be appropriate. But that is just for the moves.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. Makes sense if you think about it. Sorry for any confusion I caused up there, and thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class which does not have copy constructor or operator= overloaded.

In that case, the compiler provides these for you.  Quoting the C++ 2003 standard, clause 12.8:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared *implicitly*. … The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form
>   `X::X(const X&)` [or] `X::X(X&)`. … The implicitly-defined copy constructor for class X performs a memberwise copy of its subobjects.

and

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared *implicitly*. … The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form `X& X::operator=(const X&)` [or] `X& X::operator=(X&)`. … The implicitly-defined copy assignment operator for class X performs memberwise assignment of its subobjects.